# Display multiple specific records in a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2013

Let's say I have a single table called "Customers". It contains 2 fields:

```
Name
Address
```

I want users to be able to select multiple records by selecting their names. For example something like having a list box containing all the names of the records in the database. I want users to be able to select multiple items like:

```
Dave Richardson
Bob Smith
Sophie Parker
```

And then only display records with these names in the report.

Comment: You might need VBA to do this. Do you want to?

Comment: Yeah I expected it to require VBA. That is fine with me. Unfortunately this is a requirement of my database and Google does not provide much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *WhereCondition* option of the [DoCmd.OpenReport Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) to filter your report as needed.

```vb
Const cstrReport As String = "YourReportNameHere"
Dim custNames As String
Dim lItem As Variant
Dim strWhereCondition As String

With Me.yourListBoxName
    For Each lItem In .ItemsSelected
        custNames = custNames & ",'" & Replace(.ItemData(lItem), "'", "''") & "'"
    Next
End With

If Len(custNames) > 0 Then
    custNames = Mid(custNames, 2)
    strWhereCondition = "[Name] IN (" & custNames & ")"
End If

DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:=cstrReport, View:=acViewPreview, _
    WhereCondition:=strWhereCondition
```

Note this approach has features in common with PaulFrancis' answer. In fact, I copied his code and modified it.  The key difference is that this approach does not require you to revise a saved query in order to filter the report.

Comment: Hans, I could not get my head around using the IN clause in the OpenReport method, so my strategy to modify the Query, I did think of it to begin with. Well, a new lesson learnt. Thank you (+1)

Comment: You're welcome, PF.  I appreciate your contributions and am pleased you found this one useful.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The setup I would I have is, a Form with a SubForm and a ListBox, the Listbox will have the names of all your customers. So the RowSource would be,

```
SELECT 
    customerNameFieldName
FROM
    yourTableName;
```

The `Multi Select` property will be setup to `Extended`. Then a button will have the following code that will generate the SQL for the SubForm's recordsource.

```
Private Sub buttonName_Click()
    Dim lItem As Varaint, strSQL As String
    Dim custNames As String, whereStr As String
    Dim dbObj As dao.Database
    Dim tmpQryDef As QueryDef

    Set dbObj = CurrentDb()

    For Each lItem In Me.yourListBoxName.ItemsSelected
        custNames = custNames & "'" & Me.yourListBoxName.ItemData(lItem) & "', "
    Next

    Id Len(custNames) <> 0 Then
        custNames = Left(custNames, Len(custNames) - 2)

        whereStr = "WHERE customerNameFieldName IN (" & custNames & ")"
    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT someFields FROM someTable " & whereStr

    Set tmpQryDef = dbObj.QueryDefs("Summary 3 Q1")
    tmpQryDef.SQL = strSQL

    DoCmd.OpenReport "yourReportName", acViewNormal

    Set dbObj = Nothing
    Set tmpQryDef = Nothing 
End Sub
```

So now the SubForm will have the RecordSource based on all the information you have selected in the ListBox.

Comment: Also remember to set the listbox to multi select property either simple or extended.

Comment: Looks very promising, I tried to adapt it to my situation but to no success. I have a form with the list box on multi select containing the names, but the button has to open a report. The report in question already exists and this will basically just be an optional feature. How can I apply this to my situation? Many Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the Query that the report is based on?

Comment: The query name is "Summary 3 Q1"